# How do i map a texture to a curved path?

Tags: texturing, uv, error

I have for a while now tried to map a texture to a curved road for a game map, but it doesn't let me do "Follow Active Quads" so I can straighten it.

[image]

[image]

Instead I get this error:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\startup\bl_operators\uvcalc_follow_active.py", line 260, in execute
    main(context, self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\startup\bl_operators\uvcalc_follow_active.py", line 234, in main
    assert((status & STATUS_ERR_ACTIVE_FACE) != 0)
AssertionError
```

And I've tried for the longest to find a fix but I cant, any ideas?

Comment: As the name Active **Quads** implies you need a mesh with four sided faces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Follow Active Quads" need meshes conformed by quads faces, to unwrap this, first convert all faces to quads. Select all faces, press Ctrl+F key and select "Tris to Quads" option.

[image: Tris to quads]

With "Follow Active Quads" mapping the result is not aligned yet.

[image: Follow Active Quads]

To get a better result first choose the "Lightmap Pack" option with this option we get squares on the UV map

[image: Lightmap pack]
[image: UV with squares]

Then use the "Follow Active Quad" mapping option and you will get a better result.

[image: Follow active quad better]

Comment: bro thank u sooo much, i didnt know tris to quads existed, thank u!